# MatplotLib move ticks on top and right axis inside only

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis, xticks

I would like to move the ticks on my plot to the inside but only on the top and right axis.
This is the code I am using

```
ax.tick_params(top=True, right=True, which='both')

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
```

Here is how it looks using my code:

[image: How it looks with my code]

This is an example of the style of axis I want:

[image: Other graph]

Answer (score 0):

I figured a solution, probably not the best way to do this but I used the *twinx* and *twiny*.

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))

ax2 = plt.twinx()
ax2.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax2.tick_params(which='both', direction='in')
ax2.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])

ax3 = plt.twiny()
ax3.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax3.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax3.tick_params(which='both', direction='in')
```

I replaced the above code with this removing the initial use of tick_params.

[image: Solution]